# understanding memory report sql server

Tags: sql-server, memory

I would like to be able to understand more clearly the below standard report…

-What is MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL and why is it #1?

-Page life expectancy looks low… what can I do to increase that number?

-What’s the difference between a latched and a dirty buffer page? Is it ok for dirty to be > latched?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you asking? Do you have an actual performance problem? Any database server will use as much RAM as possible to cache data and avoid hitting the disk. The buffer pool provides the RAM pages for that cache. SQL Server doesn't leak if that's what you thought

Comment: The memory usage is explained in SQL Server's documentation by the way (Books Online) and a lot of articles. A very good (and short) intro is Brent Ozar's [A Sysadmin’s Guide to Microsoft SQL Server Memory](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. -What is MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL and why is it #1?

All the data pages

> 2. -Page life expectancy looks low… what can I do to increase that number?

Add RAM; revise your queries, bay be large scans are performed where index seek can be used

> 3. -What’s the difference between a latched and a dirty buffer page? Is it ok for dirty to be > latched?

dirty pages = modified pages; latched = where the latch is put on